# Apple mach-O linker error, file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, error-handling, linker-errors

**This is the error I get:**

> ld: file not found:
>   /Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DogiPad-ecwgmttugvxefyanpzmtfcovhaem/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dog.app/Dog
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

I tried some solutions I found on google but nothing helped..
How to solve?

Comment: Did you try to clean the project and delete the derrived data?

Answer (score 0):

Your post does not contain sufficient information to determine what the problem is. You need to engage in standard troubleshooting techniques:

- identify specific details implied by the error message but not explicitly stated: e.g. The message says a file isn't found, but not what file. Identify the file in question.
- follow the troubleshooting instructions given in the error message: "Use -v to see invocation"
- Once you have the exact command that produces the error message, determine what the command is intended to do, what it's actually doing, what it should be doing, what pre-requisites the command depends on, and if, how, and where those pre-requisites are being met.

At this point troublshooting is simply a search problem: follow the links to other build steps to figure out what should be happening that isn't or what isn't happening that should be. The problem could be anywhere in the build process and you have to understand build processes well enough to know what should be happening and see how that's different from what is happening.

Comment: what do they mean with use -v? I press "V" but nothing happens

Comment: @sdd You need to go into the build log and expand the light green colored text area to see the command Xcode is running which produces that error and the text "use -v to see invocation". Then you need to open Terminal.app and run that same command manually, verifying that you get the same error. If so, then you need to follow the instructions and modify the command by adding a `-v` flag, then run the new command. I recommend pasting the command into a text editor and modifying it there first, because the commands Xcode runs are very long and cumbersome to modify directly in Terminal